# Ext JS set color for words of a string inside a grid cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I am trying to set different colors for different words inside a string, and this string is inside a ExtJs grid cell. 
For example, I have a string 'Red Blue Green'. I need use three colors for these three words. 
This is not that hard in javascript by fontcolor, but I cannot figure out how to do it in Ext Js grid store. Could anyone give some insight on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a custom column [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer):

```
renderer: function(value){
    var words = value.split(' ');
    return '<span style="color:#f00">'+words[0]+'</span><span style="color:#0f0">'+words[1]+'</span><span style="color:#00f">'+words[2]+'</span>';
}
```

if every value has three words.